# Questions on using Microsoft VS Code as Notepad

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-word, formatting, notepad, visual-studio-code

Im not a programmer or coder, Im a data entry staff encoding Text Books and Magazine Texts. Im using either MS-Wrod or Notepad at work. I stumbled upon this MS VS Code, it's a good typing platform, so fast ie: scrolling the cursor from top to bottom, fast when moving around and other cool things, also it has the black theme which is nice for the eye. I like this VS code.

Its nice, but I want to get rid of those programming stuffs - those that's popping up from time to time (like keyword suggestions, syntax, etc.). Is there any way to get rid of those, like turning ALL those features OFF?

Also, can I (in purpose) make some texts bold if I want to? Or italics, underlined, colored, etc?

Is there anything I can do to achieve it, like installing any plugins, extensions, or something else?

Thanks,
Marie

Comment: Visual Studio Code is not a rich text editor. It only deals with plain text files. If you need formatting, you have to use a rich text editor, like Word. Word 2016 also offers a dark theme, though the document view will remain white.

Comment: @Daniel B : Thanks for the info. Okay, if I cannot format texts there, ok thats still fine. But how can I turn all those programming stuffs OFF (ie: keyword suggestions, syntax suggestions, and others)? And use it purely for typing?

Comment: IDEs usually aren't designed to just edit plain text files with. If you really need a text editor which supports formatting, I'd recommend Onenote, which is free and can back up your notes to the cloud if you want. Alternatively, I often see Notepad++ and Sublime Text recommended for both coding and note-taking (but there's no formatting unless you like markup).

Comment: @Sonickyle27 : MarkUp, what is that MarkUp thing, how to use it? Is it use to markup certain texts to distinguish it from the other. Okay, I'll try to research about that markups. Can you tell me more about that MarkUp, how to benefit on that? Thanks.

Comment: Ah sorry, I meant to say markdown. It's a formatting syntax that uses symbols to specify formatting. Wikipedia has some examples [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown#Example).

Comment: @Sonickyle27 : Hi, how can use that MarkDown you were saying? Is it automatic in VS-Code, like when I type <h>text</h>, it will automatically bold the text?